# How to update sys.login_token without restart SQL Server Service

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I query sys.login_token to check if the current user is in a particular windows group.

```
SELECT principal_id, name, [type], usage
FROM sys.login_token
WHERE principal_id > 0
```

But after I added the user to a new group, the group didn't show up in the query result.

I tried to log out and disconnect but it appears only restart the SQL Server Service will refresh the result of sys.login_token.

Therefore, is there any way(stored procedure or something) that I can trigger SQL Server to update sys.login_token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *client* refreshes the login token, not SQL Server.

Either log out/in, or lock+unlock their PC
This forces an AD authentication(token rebuild)

There also other methods...

- [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/336250/how-do-you-force-an-update-to-a-users-group-membership-in-windows-7) also suggest crashing explorer.exe on the client
- I've not tried the [klist](http://woshub.com/how-to-refresh-ad-groups-membership-without-user-logoff/) approach. YMMV

Until the token is rebuilt, the login token as read by SQL Server will be stale.

Comment: You were right, re-login will refresh it and when I tested logout yesterday I queried from another machine by ssms and didn't reconnect which make sense the result set didn't change at all, silly me.